# Upsert is duplicating enteries, How do I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, duplicates, sequelize.js, upsert, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to upsert a query result from a combination of different tables, into a central table for a new app module.

```
models.sequelize.query(
    `
      SELECT...FROM...WHERE...
  `,
    {
      type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    }
  )        
.then(function(results) {
          _.each(results, function (result) {
              promises.push(models.tableName.upsert(
              {
                id: result.id,
                poisitionId: result.positionId,
                column3: result.column3,
                column4: result.column4,
                column5: result.column5,
                column6: result.column6,
                column7: result.column7,
                column8: result.column8,
                column9: result.column9
              }, {
                conflict: {
                  target: 'id'
                }
              }
```

From what I understand the problem is that I haven't correctly implemented the conflict target portion of the code.

I would like the function to only insert new rows of data that it pulls through the query from other tables. Otherwise it should only update rows of data if any changes have been made, using positionId as the conflict target id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution was to add a unique constraint in the database to that specific table I was upserting to.

I am using pgAdmin so it was very easy to just add a unique constraint.